# Comparing tuples using regex? Python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary where the keys are tuples of n elements. Say I want to find only tuples whose n-1 elements match, and the other one can be of any value. For example, I want the first 6th elements to be set to 100, and the 7th can be anything and I have these tuples as keys:

```
 1. (100,100,100,100,100,45,54)
 2. (100,100,100,100,100,100,54)
 3. (100,100,100,100,100,100,54)
 4. (100,100,100,100,100,100,54)
 5. (100,100,100,100,100,23,54)
```

Then I only need key 2-4, as the first and the fifth hold a value different than 100 in the 6th element.
Of course I can compare each element individually when going over all keys, but I am thinking maybe there's a better way.
Any ideas of how I can do it in Python?

Thanks

Comment: You have duplicate keys in this dictionary, which isn't generally allowed.  Can you correct the samples with actual examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
matched = [x for x in dict.keys if len(set(x[:6])) == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a list comprehension:

```
matched = [x for x in tuples if x[:6] == (100,100,100,100,100,100)]
```

Comment: The answer should be generalized. The first 6 elements can be same but not 100, right?